# Is this possible to integrate HERE API in ReactNative to develop an application?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, here-api

I would like to develop an application using Here API. I'm implementing my code with ReactNative but I don't know if it support Here API. I've seen in the documentation that we can use it with React to develop a website but I'm not sure it's possible with ReactNative for an application.

Do you have any idea please ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use following code to setup a template

```
npm i -g create-react-app 
create-react-app here-react-intro
```

for more information you can refer to the tutorial [link](https://developer.here.com/tutorials/react/)